# kafka streams application only prints when application is killed

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-streams-scala

I created a kafka streams scala g8 template but I noticed it only prints when the application is killed. I also tried the print to file and noticed the file is only updated when the application is killed.

https://github.com/idarlington/kafka-streams.g8/blob/master/src/main/g8/src/main/scala/%24package__packaged%24/WordCount.scala#L43

Is this an expected behaviour?

Comment: I assume you are hitting: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7326 -- use `foreach` with `System.out.println()` as workaround or upgrade to 2.1

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax, upgrading resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

As [Matthias.J.Sax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4953079/matthias-j-sax) pointed out, this is a bug in Kafka `2.0.0`. Upgrading to `2.1.0` resolved it.